# How to prevent new user's registration on JHipster

Tags: jhipster

I want to create a closed community. So I wold have a lot of users but all of them will be invited by myself or somebody.
Moreover I want them to have only one option to login - social accounts.

I've implemented this functionality but for me it looks like set of hack:
1) forbid `/api/register` endpoint to prevent self registration by the registration form
2) Do not create new user if it is still has not been created (here  `SocialService#createUserIfNotExist`)
3) Modify some email templates

My questions now are:
1) Is it is right way or you can suggest better solution?
2) Do you think that it may be a good option for further JHipster generator?

Comment: I think it's an interesting feature that could be implemented as an addition to JHipster or as a module. You should open an issue on github. Personally, I'd think it'd be also useful to other auth than social. We could have a new role (e.g. ROLE_REGISTRAR or ROLE_INVITER) to allow some or all users to invite new ones.

Comment: don't forget, JHipster is generating some sample code for you. Building custom solutions doesn't mean you do a hack.

Answer (score 3):

The most important thing is first to block the backend calls to the `/api/register` endpoint by blacklisting it using [.denyAll()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#el-common-built-in) in the [security configuration](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/9834246f316fe976db9b3013278367c0fdbfdc68/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/config/SecurityConfiguration.java#L83). This will right away reject any request with **HTTP 401 Unauthorized**.
Secondarily you can work backwards and remove frontend and backend call.

Answer (score 0):

Open the corresponding route file (I think it's `account` ) and delete the entry to register, then open the login HTML file and delete the part referring to the registration. That should do the trick

Comment: this will still leave the backend accessible